# In a trigger in Oracle, how to get the information out of the `where` from an update?

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Say we have a simple table:

```
ID | Name

1  | "A"

2  | "B"
```

An update can be

```
update set Name = "C" where ID = 1
```

So when creating a trigger, I know how to get the new row's info by `:NEW.`, but the ID won't be in there as I tried.

How can I get the `ID` information out of the newly updated row?

Comment: You can refer to `:new.id` too; all columns in the row are available, not just those that were modified. Since ID won't have changed (hopefully) you could use `:old` or `:new` for that in an update trigger and get the same value. So perhaps you should show the actual code you have that doesn't compile, along with your real table definition, your real update statement, and the error you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly did you try? The following works for me:

```
set serveroutput on;

drop table test;

create table test (id number, name varchar2(10));

insert into test values (1, 'A');
insert into test values (2, 'B');
commit;

create or replace trigger test_trg
before update on test
for each row
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('id of row being updated is: '||:old.id||' and it''s new value is: '||:new.id);
end;
/

update test
set name = 'C'
where id = 1;

commit;
```

and the output I got was:

```
Table dropped.
Table created.
1 row created.
1 row created.
Commit complete.
Trigger created.
id of row being updated is: 1 and it's new value is: 1
1 row updated.
Commit complete.
```

Bear in mind that if you ever do batch operations on the table in question that is covered by the scope of a for-each-row-trigger, you're going to turn it from a set operation into a row-by-row operation, so you will see performance degredation. I'd also question what it is you're using the trigger to do; in my experience, you can do most things without needing to resort to a trigger!

Answer (score 0):

Simply refer it as **":OLD.column-name"**.

In a Row-level UPDATE trigger, `:OLD` represents the existing value in the column, prior to the update being applied.

In your case, you could do -

```
old_id := :old.ROWID
```